# Difference between java.awt.Color and javafx.scene.paint.Color

Tags: java, colors, javafx

I noticed that JavaFX defines its own Color class which seems superficially very similar to the old java.awt.Color class. They both represent RGB colours with alpha values.

What is the difference between the two, and is there any reason to prefer using one or the other for general usage?

Answer (score 2):

If you're programming a JavaFX application, use the JavaFX Color class. If you're programming an AWT/Java2D/Swing application, use the awt Color class. There is no real difference between them, but they are intended for use in their respective UI toolkits only.

Comment: and if you're embedding a JavaFX scene in a Swing application? :-)